# How to programmatically set an element in a nested list, given indices?

Tags: python

I'd like to set an element in an arbitrarily-nested list given a list of indices. For instance, let's say we have the list:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

We could set an element like this:

```
a[1][2] = 9
```

The modified list `a` is then:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 9]]
```

I'd like to set this element given the list of indices: `[1, 2]`.

Thanks!

Edit for clarity: the length of the index list can vary. For example, given the index list: `idx = [1, 2]`, as suggested, we can do:

```
a[idx[0]][idx[1]] = 9
```

However, in the more general case, `idx` may be any length. I want something like:

```
a[idx[i_1]][idx[i_2]][...][idx[i_n]] = 9
```

Comment: it may help clarify your intentions to show the before and after for a in your example

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `b = [1, 2]` `a[b[0]][b[1]] = 9`

Comment: @ASmallShellScript: Thanks, I have added what the list should be after the modification.

Comment: when you say "arbitrarily-nested list", do you mean the list of indices could be of any length, or is it always 2 deep as in your example [x, y], but that x and y could be any value?

Comment: @ASmallShellScript: The list of indices can be of any length. Please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
def set_in_list(a, idx, val):

    """
        Set an element to value `val` in a nested list `a`. The position
        of the element to set is given by the list `idx`.

        Example:

        `a` = [[1, 2], [3, [4, 5], 6], [7]]
        `idx` = [1,1,0]
        `val` = 9

        ==> `a` = [[1, 2], [3, [9, 5], 6], [7]]

    """

    for i in range(len(idx) - 1):

        a = a[idx[i]]

    a[idx[-1]] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with recursion:

```
def get_deep(l, indices):
     if (len(indices) > 1) and isinstance(l[indices[0]], list):
         return get_deep(l[indices[0]], indices[1:])
     else:
         return l[indices[0]]

def set_deep(l, indices, value):
     if (len(indices) > 1) and isinstance(l[indices[0]], list):
         set_deep(l[indices[0]], indices[1:], value)
     else:
         l[indices[0]] = value
```

So:

```
In [19]: a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

In [20]: get_deep(a, [1, 2])
Out[20]: 5

In [21]: set_deep(a, [1, 2], 9)

In [22]: a
Out[22]: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 9]]
```

Note that if you change the `list` class in to `(list, dict)`, etc. then this will also work with mixed nested dicts/lists.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary indexed by tuples:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_dict[4, 5] = 3
my_dict[4, 6] = 'foo'
my_dict[2, 7] = [1, 2, 3]


for key in my_dict:
    print(key, my_dict[key])

# (4, 5) 3
# (4, 6) foo
# (2, 7) [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this to get o/p: [[1, 9], [3, 4, 9]]

```
 a = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
    z=len(a)
    for i in range(0,z):
        a[i][len(a[i])-1]=9
    print (a,len(a[0]))
```

Comment: i think your question is how to  change the value of last element of each inner list to 9,is it?

Comment: @S T Mohammed: This was just an example. In general the list will be arbitrarily-nested so they may be more than two levels. I'd like to be able to set an element whose position is defined by a list of indices. Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify your question more by giving a example having both input and expected output,from your given  example i thought you need to change the value of last element of each inner list to 9